# Is there anyway to upload multiple image in my blog?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

'''
views.py
''' 
I can upload single image in my db. I want to upload multiple image. Is their anyway to solve the problem.helphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelp

```
class IndexView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        slide = Slider.objects.all()
        blogslide = BlogSlider.objects.all()
        post_form = PostForm()
        paginator = Paginator(blogslide, 3)
        page = request.GET.get('page')

        blogslide = paginator.get_page(page)
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'slide': slide, 'blogslide': blogslide, 'post_form': post_form})

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        post_form = PostForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES or None)
        if post_form.is_valid():
        title = post_form.cleaned_data['title']
        sub_title = post_form.cleaned_data['sub_title']
        description = post_form.cleaned_data['description']
        image = post_form.cleaned_data['image']

        p = BlogSlider(
            description = description,
            image = image,
            title = title,
            sub_title = sub_title,
            user = self.request.user,       
        )
        p.save()
        #return JsonResponse({'newcomic': model_to_dict(p)}, status=200)
        return redirect('/')
```

'''
forms.py
This is my form help help help help help help help help helphelp
'''

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    image = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
    class Meta:
        model = BlogSlider
        fields = ('title', 'sub_title', 'description',)
```

'''
models.py
 this is model.helphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelp
'''

```
class BlogSlider(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.sub_title)
        super(BlogSlider, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-details', kwargs={
            'slug':self.slug
        })
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a different model (say blogImageFields) in which you have `blogslider.id` as a foreign key and ImageField as the second field. For mulitple images, use add query in `blogImageFields` so your table's data will look like this:

BlogID ,     ImageField

1      ,     image1

1      ,      image2

1      ,   image3

2     ,    image1

i.e. your blog with id=1 has three images now.

Comment: There is no limit here. You can add as much photos as you like against each blog entry

Comment: can't understand

Comment: You can understand it by concepts of normalization. This solution is according to 1NF rule which states that there should be no list in any cell i.e. the values are atomic. You can google it for better understanding. Hope that will clarify that you can associate multiple images to one blog in a separate table. 

P.S. You can not insert same blog id twice in your model because of primary key constraint thats why separate table is required